# How to keep the values on a registration form in html & javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to create a registration form on a website with some basic html and javascript, and after figuring I made a short checker if both passwords were the same.

But whenever I press on submit all the values of the fields disappear how can I fix this?

I tried searching it on the web but it didnt help.

```
<form id="registerform" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
First name:<br>
<label>
    <input type="text" required="required" name="getfirstname">
</label><br>
Prefix:<br>
<input type="text" name="prefix"><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" required="required" name="lastname"><br>
Email address:<br>
<input type="email" required="required" name="email"><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" required="required" name="password"><br>
Password2:<br>
<input type="password" required="required" name="password2"><br>
<input type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>

function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["registerform"]["password"].value;
var y = document.forms["registerform"]["password2"].value;
if (y != x){
    alert("The passwords do not match. Please try again!");
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: If your looking to keep the value after a submit it best to only do so if their was an issue with data submitted. It really depends on what server language your using. In a Java Web Application I use `<input type="text" name="email" value="${email}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, for one you can submit the form with an AJAX request, save the data then fill it back in as soon as the form was submitted.

But why would you want to do this? What the user fills in should be cleared on submit.

If you just want to see the name of the input after you submit just use the placeholder tag, it can display a text in an input, clear that text when you start typing, and put it back when the form is empty:

```html
<input placeholder="text">
```

Comment: well im trying to make it so if its incorrectly filled or it doesnt match u dont have to put in ur values again.

Comment: then fire the form submit event only after you successfully validate the forms

don't rely on the backend validation, validate the form with javascript and only fire the submit action after validation

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form id="registerform" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
```

to

```
<form id="registerform" name="registerform" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
```

to access form controls by name like in `document.forms["registerform"]["password"]` and ensure your javascript code is inside a `script` tag and returns `true` if validation is Ok.

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
 var x = document.forms["registerform"]["password"].value;
 var y = document.forms["registerform"]["password2"].value;
 if (y != x){
    alert("The passwords do not match. Please try again!");
    return false;
 }
 return true;
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/FranIg/pxgcbtLo/

Comment: Well it does work with the jsfiddle but with my Webstorm it will still submit without getting an alert.

Comment: Check the js console and view if there is an error like 'validateForm is not defined'. In this case, you need to define the function as a global variable, like in the fiddle (`window.validateForm=function() { }`)

Comment: Ok you can accept the answer as a solution for your question.

Comment: @Igor I corrected the code so that the form start tag no longer contains two `name` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to specify that it is a javascript's function with tag ...

```js
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["registerform"]["password"].value;
var y = document.forms["registerform"]["password2"].value;
if (y != x){
    alert("The passwords do not match. Please try again!");
    return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function formValidation()  
{  
var uid = document.registration.userid;  
var passid = document.registration.passid;  
var uname = document.registration.username;  
var uadd = document.registration.address;  
var ucountry = document.registration.country;  
var uzip = document.registration.zip;  
var uemail = document.registration.email;  
var umsex = document.registration.msex;  
var ufsex = document.registration.fsex; if(userid_validation(uid,5,12))  
{  
if(passid_validation(passid,7,12))  
{  
if(allLetter(uname))  
{  
if(alphanumeric(uadd))  
{   
if(countryselect(ucountry))  
{  
if(allnumeric(uzip))  
{  
if(ValidateEmail(uemail))  
{  
if(validsex(umsex,ufsex))  
{  
}  
}   
}  
}   
}  
}  
}  
}  
return false;  
  
} function userid_validation(uid,mx,my)  
{  
var uid_len = uid.value.length;  
if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx)  
{  
alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);  
uid.focus();  
return false;  
}  
return true;  
}  
function passid_validation(passid,mx,my)  
{  
var passid_len = passid.value.length;  
if (passid_len == 0 ||passid_len >= my || passid_len < mx)  
{  
alert("Password should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);  
passid.focus();  
return false;  
}  
return true;  
}  
function allLetter(uname)  
{   
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(uname.value.match(letters))  
{  
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
uname.focus();  
return false;  
}  
}  
function alphanumeric(uadd)  
{   
var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;  
if(uadd.value.match(letters))  
{  
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('User address must have alphanumeric characters only');  
uadd.focus();  
return false;  
}  
}  
function countryselect(ucountry)  
{  
if(ucountry.value == "Default")  
{  
alert('Select your country from the list');  
ucountry.focus();  
return false;  
}  
else  
{  
return true;  
}  
}  
function allnumeric(uzip)  
{   
var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
if(uzip.value.match(numbers))  
{  
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('ZIP code must have numeric characters only');  
uzip.focus();  
return false;  
}  
}  
function ValidateEmail(uemail)  
{  
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if(uemail.value.match(mailformat))  
{  
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");  
uemail.focus();  
return false;  
}  
} function validsex(umsex,ufsex)  
{  
x=0;  
  
if(umsex.checked)   
{  
x++;  
} if(ufsex.checked)  
{  
x++;   
}  
if(x==0)  
{  
alert('Select Male/Female');  
umsex.focus();  
return false;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('Form Succesfully Submitted');  
window.location.reload()  
return true;  
}  
}
```

```css
h1 {  
margin-left: 70px;  
}  
form li {  
list-style: none;  
margin-bottom: 5px;  
}  
  
form ul li label{  
float: left;  
clear: left;  
width: 100px;  
text-align: right;  
margin-right: 10px;  
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
font-size:14px;  
}  
  
form ul li input, select, span {  
float: left;  
margin-bottom: 10px;  
}  
  
form textarea {  
float: left;  
width: 350px;  
height: 150px;  
}  
  
[type="submit"] {  
clear: left;  
margin: 20px 0 0 230px;  
font-size:18px  
}  
  
p {  
margin-left: 70px;  
font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en"><head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>JavaScript Form Validation using a sample registration form</title>  
<meta name="keywords" content="example, JavaScript Form Validation, Sample registration form" />  
<meta name="description" content="This document is an example of JavaScript Form Validation using a sample registration form. " />  
<link rel='stylesheet' href='js-form-validation.css' type='text/css' />  
<script src="sample-registration-form-validation.js"></script>  
</head>  
<body onload="document.registration.userid.focus();">  
<h1>Registration Form</h1>  
<p>Use tab keys to move from one input field to the next.</p>  
<form name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation();">  
<ul>  
<li><label for="userid">User id:</label></li>  
<li><input type="text" name="userid" size="12" /></li>  
<li><label for="passid">Password:</label></li>  
<li><input type="password" name="passid" size="12" /></li>  
<li><label for="username">Name:</label></li>  
<li><input type="text" name="username" size="50" /></li>  
<li><label for="address">Address:</label></li>  
<li><input type="text" name="address" size="50" /></li>  
<li><label for="country">Country:</label></li>  
<li><select name="country">  
<option selected="" value="Default">(Please select a country)</option>  
<option value="AF">Australia</option>  
<option value="AL">Canada</option>  
<option value="DZ">India</option>  
<option value="AS">Russia</option>  
<option value="AD">USA</option>  
</select></li>  
<li><label for="zip">ZIP Code:</label></li>  
<li><input type="text" name="zip" /></li>  
<li><label for="email">Email:</label></li>  
<li><input type="text" name="email" size="50" /></li>  
<li><label id="gender">Sex:</label></li>  
<li><input type="radio" name="msex" value="Male" /><span>Male</span></li>  
<li><input type="radio" name="fsex" value="Female" /><span>Female</span></li>  
<li><label>Language:</label></li>  
<li><input type="checkbox" name="en" value="en" checked /><span>English</span></li>  
<li><input type="checkbox" name="nonen" value="noen" /><span>Non English</span></li>  
<li><label for="desc">About:</label></li>  
<li><textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea></li>  
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>  
</ul>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```